# What Bayesian test to conduct with one independent variable and two dependent variables?

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference

In my current study I am looking at the effects of creatine monohydrate ingestion on ground reaction force and repeated sprint times. With CM as the independent variable, and ground reaction force and repeated sprint times as the dependent variables, what Bayesian inferential test would be the best to conduct?

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian inference would, in theory, involve determining the joint probability distribution (JPD) $P(R,S,C)$ that expresses the probability of a certain combination of reaction force ($R$), sprint time ($S$) and creatine monohydrate ingestion ($C$). The JPD over all variables can later be used to infer all other possible conditional probabilities using Bayes's rule. $P(R,S,C)$, can using this same rule, be factorised as $P(R|S,C)\times P(S|C)\times P(C)$. With an eye on what you probably want to infer, you just need to is estimate the probability $P(R|S,C)$ of different reaction force's ($R$) given a certain value for repeated sprint time ($S$) and CM ingestion ($C$). The same can be done for $P(S|C)$.

**Estimating** these probability **distributions** can either be done using continuous variables in which you would make certain assumptions about the functional form of your distribution and fit its parameters. Or you could bin your data in discrete intervals and **count occurrences** per interval.

Once you estimated $P(R|S,C)$ and $P(S|C)$, the distribution of reaction force ($R$) given a certain CM ingestion ($C=c$) (which can be used to **infer** it's most probable value) is expressed as :

$$ P(R|C=c) = \frac{P(R,C=c)}{P(C=c)}=\frac{\sum_S P(R,S,C=c)}{P(C=c)}=\sum_S P(R|S,C=c)\times P(S|C=c) $$

Or infer the complete distribution over both $R$ and $S$ given given a certain CM ingestion ($C=c$)

$$ P(R,S|C=c) = \frac{P(R,S,C=c)}{P(C=c)}= P(R|S,C=c)\times P(S|C=c) $$
Using these distributions, you can also determine the standard deviation, confidence intervals, etc.

**Side note:** You could also choose a different factorisation that might better suite your data, in the end the probabilities you infer will stay the same, these "factors" just serve as a way to make estimating your JPD practical. I did not assume any independence between $R$ and $S$, as this seems very unlikely. This would however ease the computation of $P(R|S,C)$ which would then  $=P(R|C)$.

Answer (score 1):

One promising approach is to formulate the two marginal Bayesian models just as we always do, then to model the dependency of the two outcomes using a copula.  That way posterior inference can be done marginally as always but you could also make efficient joint statements regarding unions or intersections of conditions (assertions) involving the two outcomes and their association with the independent variable.  I've been looking for a good example of specifying a copula model in `Stan` --- I hope someone can find one and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Bayes' rule states

$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)},
$$
where $P(A|B)$ and $P(B|A)$ are conditional probabilities. For instance, $P(A|B)$ is the probability of $A$ occurring given that $B$ is observed.

Bayesian inferencing is a method of inference (there are others) that applies Bayes' rule in order to update our beliefs of a certain hypothesis given observed (experimental) parameters. Technically, it involves calculating the conditional posterior distribution; that is, the conditional distribution of the random variable of interest post-observation.

Often the most contentious part of the process is deciding what your priors are. In the formula above that deals with probabilities instead of distributions, $P(A)$ would be our "prior" probability; that is, the probability of $A$ occurring *prior* to any experimental observation.

---

You mention wanting to inference the effect of one variable on two outcome variables. Do you have reason to believe that the two outcome variables are independent of one another?

Answer (score 0):

One of the advantages of Baysian analysis is the flexibility to tailor your analysis to knowledge you have apart from your observed data as opposed to Frequentist analysis, where many researchers live with standard answers.

Not having any more knowledge about your specific field and data sources we have to rely on standard answers. A good standard answer would be: Start with a simple linear regression model (or two models in this case) and see how that fits or if you find a way to improve the fit. Maybe quadratic terms or logarithmic terms, ... Maybe your theory gives you a good way to connect the two independent variables and you can come up with a model that comprises this connection.